# How does an IMAP client choose names to create/use for special folders, because I have 3 "Sent" folders in Outlook

Tags: email, outlook, imap, dovecot, regional-settings

Outlook, IOS and Android clients, as well as the built-in Web-Interface client of this Installation all seem to use different IMAP folder naming schemes.

The current bulk of users on that system use Outlook 2010. As well as the above, I also need to support WP, Thunderbird(Cross-Platform).

Some clients have easy ways to change the folder assignment for (sometimes only some of) the special folders, some I haven't found easy ways yet, and for some I'm unsure of even the possibility.

Outlook here is a special case, as it creates localized folder names (`.&AMk-l&AOk-ments envoy&AOk-s` means `.Éléments envoyés`) server-side.
IOS (i think) also does this, but has options to change the foldernames used)

This leads to folder mess in Outlook, if the users have used several mailbox access clients.

Is there some kind of Server-Protocol, or Option I could enable on the client or server (dovecot here) to force usage of "International, short names" server-side (Sent, Trash, Drafts, Junk, Inbox, Infected), and let the client bother with translation to the users regional settings? (Like the "C:\Users\ folder in windows already does it).

Or any other way to force Outlook to not create/use non-english folders?

EDIT: Outlook<2013 has options to move some of the imap folders. Later version support some subset of RFC6154 (XLIST).

But I still have not found, how to change the outlook defaults (policy, reg-key, whatever) for Outlook<2013 and Servers without XLIST.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in Outlook 2013+ to change the IMAP folders except using RFC 6154 on the server. On Servers without XLIST Outlook 2013 seems to do some "guessing" which often fails. The documentation on how to do this in dovecot is here: http://wiki.dovecot.org/MailboxSettings

This will not help you with existing clients though, since outlook checks this only on the initial connection. You might try outlook.exe /resetfoldernames, but probably removing and re-adding the account is necessary for this to take effect.